# Explaining redox reactions to a 6 year old?

Tags: redox, teaching-lab

In a similar vein and for pretty much the same reason as I post [this question on the Physics.SE site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76650/explaining-uv-radiation-to-a-6-year-old), what would be a an effective means to promote understanding about redox reactions to a 6 year old?  In particular, what (if any) simulations are available?

Comment: Why specifically redox reactions? Seems quite a challenge for a six year old to understand even what a chemical reaction is in general.

Comment: Long story behind this, but after seeing a 'redox front' in a road cross section, this child got interested in what caused it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might suggest you take a look at *What's Chemistry All About* by Frith, Gillespie and Larkum.  (ISBN: 1409547078)  It is a very approachable book that in my mind pays close attention to the science jargon introduced to its audience.  Redox reactions are described in the section "Let's make things happen" under the types of reactions.  A bit of history about where the name oxidation comes from and the safety symbol that you will see on an oxidizing agent are both included in the brief discussion.

The example reactions given are combustion and firecrackers, which I think are appropriate and accessible to a child.

As for experiments to do, I'll suggest another book, the *Illustrated Guide to Home Chemistry Experiments* by Thompson. (ISBN: 0596514921) There is a chapter on electrochemistry with two experiments that might be of interest to a young learner: the electrolysis of water to make oxygen and hydrogen gas, and the oxidation of iron.  Of course, there's also the "make your battery" type experiments which are always fun.

As for simulations, I would suggest heading on over to the [PHet](http://phet.ucolorado.edu) website and have a stroll through all the activities there.  I don't recall off hand what they have for electrochemistry, but there's plenty to keep a budding scientist interested.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught using the OIL RIG acronym, where oxidation is loss, and reduction is gain. I would also utilise a picture of some sort showing how a oxidant is reduced, and a reducer is oxidised. I would also mention that most oxidising agents have oxygen in them, whereas reducing agents can have hydrogen. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Let's speak the Redox with an exempla : Corrosion off a piece of Iron.And Oxygene around you and me. As child of 6 years old had probably seen this, it will directly rely to everyday 's live.

Say this to him : You cannot see the "messy movements" in this Iron because your eyes are too big.......and because you can see the moon and stars.......but not all stars in the universe because we are too small. 
The idea off beeing somewhere in the middle off "The Scale" is an important step to start imaging the all around and inside off you. Back the Redox.
The iron, as all the rest is made of 3 sweeties, called Neutron...not an easy name but this is exiting for a child the knonw some specials words. As 3 new words is fine at C yers old,continue with Electron, an other one to love and Proton. Those 3 sweeties are bricks to create all you can see, fill and  smell.

Redox is when sweeties are given and received.I can not receive if nothing is given. Both are related and if one does not happens, the other one too.
A child should ask how it is possible to have only 3 sweeties too have all around with différences. More or less you have always those 
3 sweeties together exept when speaking e.g. nuclear explosion. Just catch his meaning with powerfull stuffs. Back on redox,now to have Iron you need those 3 sweeties with 25 other teams of those 3 members: E-, P+ and N°. This make 26 teams to make Iron, the very kind Iron can give some Electrons too Oxygene we need to be alive. And the volume off Iron increase as the oxygene who received some electrons must stay around the iron or leave. As they are now togheter, they will stay togheter as long as you do not found and other team off sweeties able to give back electrons too Iron or to stoll the electron owned by oxygene. Use off this ugly stuff called chlorine can make it true.
Next : Explain the exeption off nuclear phenomena ?

Regards.